# Error message "attempt to set an attribute on NULL" in R

Tags: r, nullreferenceexception

I am going through a statistics textbook on my own. I am using semi-official code (from a manual written by somebody else, but linked on the textbook's site) to calculate the examples and exercises.

The code includes a function for fitting generalized linear models. I typed it from the manual and ran it as suggested. And although the actual fitting works, I get the above error when assigning labels to the results.

The line which throws the error is

```
names(fit$part) <- dn
```

At that point, the value of `dn` is `[1] "(Intercept)" "Var1"` and the value of `fit$par` is `[1] -5.9604611  0.3165604`

I don't see any NULL there, and wonder what could cause the error.

The complete code is:

```
ct <- data.frame(alcohol.comsumption = c("0", "<1", "1-2", "3-5", ">= 6"), scores=c(0, 0.5, 1.5, 4, 7), absent = c(17066, 14464, 788, 126, 37), present = c(48, 38, 5, 1, 1))

n <- ct$absent + ct$present
alc.consumption <- rep(ct$scores, n)
y <- rep(rep(c(1,0), nrow(ct)), c(rbind(ct$present, ct$absent)))

logitreg <- function(x, y, wt = rep(1, length(y)), intercept = T, start = rep(0, p), ...)
{
  if(!exists("optim")) library(MASS)
  fmin <- function(beta, X, y, w) {
    p <- plogis(X %*% beta)
    -sum(2 * w * ifelse(y, log(p), log(1-p)))
  }
  gmin <- function(beta, X, y, w)
  {
    eta <- X %*% beta; p<-plogis(eta)
    t(-2 * (w *dlogis(eta) *ifelse(y, 1/p, -1/(1-p))))%*% X
  }
  if(is.null(dim(x))) dim(x) <- c(length(x),1)
  dn <- dimnames(x)[[2]]
  if(!length(dn)) dn <- paste("Var", 1:ncol(x), sep="")
  p <- ncol(x) + intercept
  if(intercept) {x <- cbind(1, x); dn <- c("(Intercept)", dn)}
  if(is.factor(y)) y <- (unclass(y) != 1)
  fit <- optim(start, fmin, gmin, X=x, y=y, w=wt, ...)

  # --- Next line throws the error --- #

  names(fit$part) <- dn 
  cat("\nCoefficients:\n"); print(fit$par)
  cat("\nResidual Deviance:", format(fit$value), "\n")
  cat("\nConvergence message:", fit$convergence, "\n")
  invisible(fit)
}

logit.fit<-logitreg(x=alc.consumption, y=y, hessian=T, method="BFGS")
```

Comment: Looks like either you or the book author mistyped `names(fit$par)` as `names(fit$part)`, which doesn't exist.

Comment: @ping so it was some dumb typo?! Thank you for catching that, it seems that too the hours of statistics have reduced my concentration ability more than I expected :( Please make that an answer, you absolutely deserve the easy rep.

Comment: In my experience, typos (and incorrect brackets) are a major source of frustrating errors!

Comment: Since this turned out to be a typo I have to flag this for removal. This is a red herring for those of us who have this error for non-typo reasons.

Comment: @Hack-R Well, I didn't even know that this cryptic error can be caused by a typo. So I found the question helpful. I guess we have to let the community decide if it's more important to leave it (which helps the ones who don't know that) or remove (which helps the ones who have already considered and dismissed a typo)

Comment: @rumtscho "Caused by a typographical error" is one of the pre-defined reasons for flagging a question for removal. The flagging and review process is how the community decides this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like either you or the book author mistyped `names(fit$par)` as `names(fit$part)`, which doesn't exist.